# Python: pandas.to_csv adds unwanted quotes

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I reading a CSV file with `pd.read_csv`, as shown:

`lisp = pd.read_csv('ida_lisp.ida', header=None, skip_blank_lines=False)`

I replace `%1%` with key values and save the result to different locations, as shown:

```
heating_setpoint_s = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24] 
for i in range(len(heating_setpoint_s)):
    lisp1 = lisp.replace('%1%', str(heating_setpoint_s[i]), regex=True)
    path = "C://Users//nico//"+str(i+1)+"_ida"
    os.chdir(path)
    lisp1.to_csv('ida_lisp.ida', header=False, index=False, na_rep=" ")
```

All is working fine for the exception of one line `MDESIGN ""` in the old CSV file:

```
      K2 0.0
      TAU 1.0
      SPECPUMPPO 349.0
      MDESIGN ""

  MODULE chil
    TYPE SIMCHIL
      NFPLR 0
      COP 3
```

is changed after saving, to:

```
      K1 0.0
      K2 0.0
      TAU 1.0
      SPECPUMPPO 349.0
"      MDESIGN """""

  MODULE chil
    TYPE SIMCHIL
      NFPLR 0
      COP 3
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: May we have an example of the offending line from your source IDA file, as well as a few surrounding lines for context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a couple tweaks to your code to help address this issue (in **bold**) and make things a little more straight-forward for you.

- Updated your `for` loop to iterate your `list` directly, rather than convoluting with a `range(len())` call.
- **Added a `replace` function to replace any stray `"` in your strings.**
- Added a `strip` function to clean all values to remove any leading/trailing whitespace so the output CSV is clean.
- Updated your file path concatenation to use `os.path.join`.
- Added a `os.makedirs` call in the event your storage directory does not exist.

#### Sample Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

lisp = pd.read_csv('ida_lisp.ida', header=None, skip_blank_lines=False)

heating_setpoint_s = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24] 
for i in heating_setpoint_s:
    lisp1 = lisp.replace('%1%', str(i), regex=True).replace('"+', '', regex=True)
    # Clean column 0, assuming this is the only column, based on sample data provided.
    lisp1 = lisp1.iloc[:, 0].str.strip()
    path = "C:/Users/nico/{}_ida".format(i)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    lisp1.to_csv(os.path.join(path, 'ida_lisp.ida'), header=False, index=False, na_rep="")
```

#### Input from CSV

```
      K2 0.0
      TAU 1.0
      SPECPUMPPO 349.0
      MDESIGN ""

  MODULE chil
    TYPE SIMCHIL
      NFPLR 0
      COP 3
```

#### Output:

```
K2 0.0
TAU 1.0
SPECPUMPPO 349.0
MDESIGN

MODULE chil
TYPE SIMCHIL
NFPLR 0
COP 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As per pandas documentation,  [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) has a `quotechar=` parameter which defaults to `"`, maybe you can try another symbol, say `~`, for quote char (i.e. `lisp1.to_csv('ida_lisp.ida', header=False, index=False, na_rep=" ", quotechar='~')` ). This way you can test if the problem is purely originating due to quote chars and not from your data.

Comment: this is working good for `mdesign""`. But there are other `"` which are replaced with `~`.

Comment: You will have to find a quote char that suits your purpose, try and assign `None` to quote char or maybe `'` i.e.  `quotechar="'"`